# jFeed Same Origin Policy

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, same-origin-policy, jfeed

I am trying to find a workaround for my use of jQuery jFeed & the Same Origin Policy.  I'm trying to use jFeed to parse my wordpress xml feed that is hosted on the same domain.  This is how my code is set up:

```
jQuery.getFeed({
url: 'http://mydomain.com/blog/feed',
    success: function(feed) {
        alert('success');
        }
        jQuery('#News').append(html);
    }
});
```

My code is functional though I am not able to figure out a way around the same origin policy.  This is the first time I've encountered and heard of this & I have no experience with JSON & Ajax, if somebody could help me out with this I'd appreciate it a lot.

Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can walk around the same origin policy with using [jsonp](http://json-p.org/) or the extremely cool library [easyxdm](http://easyxdm.net/wp/)